# Looking for best practice for doing a "Net Use" in C#

Tags: c#, .net-1.1

I'd rather not have to resort to calling the command line.
I'm looking for code that can map/disconnect a drive, while also having exception handling.

Any ideas?

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample working about it ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use P/Invoke and [WNetAddConnection2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385413.aspx)
There should also be some [wrappers](http://www.aejw.com/default.aspx?page=codeviewer&file=cNetworkDrive.cs&ret=dev/cnetworkdrive) out there to do some of the grunt work for you.
Google is your friend, as always.

Comment: any full real sample using wrappers ?