# Enumerating network shares

Tags: c#, network-share

Is there a part of the .net framework that enumerates the file shares on a host? I've found some things that use the WMI, but I'd prefer not to go that route.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You just want to list all the files available under \\hostname ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8919/looking-for-best-practice-for-doing-a-net-use-in-c

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use NetShareEnum win32 api.
http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/netapi32/netshareenum.html

Or look at the following project which is .NET Wrapper over it.
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/networkshares.aspx