# Get directories of remote Server

Tags: c#, directoryinfo, getdirectories

I'm trying to get all directories of a remote server.

For example:
`path: "\\Servename\folder"` - it works!

`path: "\\Servename"` - error

I tried this:

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo (@"\\SERVERNAME"); <- Error happens here
//Get Directories from \\SERVERNAME
DirectoryInfo[] dirInfos = dir.GetDirectories();
```

Error: `ERROR: The UNC path should be of the form \\server\share`

Comment: I do not think it is possible to get a list of shares this way, even though you can browse it in explorer. However, I do not have an answer, because I do not know what API covers this.

Comment: There is no `\\Servername` directory. Those are published shares on the remote computer, not file system directories. It might be possible to use WMI or SMB to enumerate the shares, but that's about it.

Comment: Actually i thought that i was working with filesystem directories. Am i doing this all wrong? If i am, how can i get all the directories just by passing the servername?

Comment: I tried use that code but doesn't work. That only show local shares and i want remote "shares". I tried with the management but gives error in access "ACCESS IS DENIED". How can give error in access if I have the impersonate working properly?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that you need to read available shares and not just the directories, as the comments answered.

However getting the list of all available shares on a server is a bit more complicated, it was already answered in a different question: [Get a list of all UNC shared folders on a local network server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3567063/get-a-list-of-all-unc-shared-folders-on-a-local-network-server)

The most voted answer was [Network Shares and UNC paths](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2939/Network-Shares-and-UNC-paths)

Comment: What is namespace of ShareCollection! The System.Collections.ReadOnlyCollection doesn't exist in visual studio 2012. I already try Management Class but give me the error "Access is Denied". And i already implement the impersonate

Comment: You need to download the source code provided on codeproject, there is the definition of `ShareCollection`

Comment: I tried use that code but doesn't work. That only show local shares and i want remote "shares". I tried with the management but gives error in access "ACCESS IS DENIED". How can give error in access if I have the impersonate working properly?