# How can I enumerate shares on a host, given that the FindXxxFile API is unable to enumerate them?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, visual-c++

In my application, there is a part where I need to list the sub-directories and files in a given path. It works fine (or so it seems :) ) for local paths, but acts weird when user enters network shared paths.

If I give network shared path `\\host_name\shared_dir\*`, my application can list all the subdirectories and files under `\\host_name\shared_dir\` but If user gives just `\\host_name\*`, then FindFirstFile fails. !!! < But user can access `\\host_name\` path in windows explorer, so there is no permission issue as such!!! >

Here is a code snippet showing the way I am using FindFirstFile

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    char l_host_name[64] = "\\\\host_name\\*"; 
    WIN32_FIND_DATA search_data = { 0 }; 
    HANDLE search_handle; 
    BOOL next_ret_val = 1; 

    search_handle = FindFirstFile(l_host_name, &search_data);
    if(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE != search_handle)
    {
        printf("Name = %s\n", search_data.cFileName); 
        do 
        {
            next_ret_val = FindNextFile(search_handle, &search_data); 
            printf("Name = %s\n", search_data.cFileName);
        } while(next_ret_val != 0);
        FindClose(search_handle);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("failed to get search handle\n"); 
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: `shared_dir` is not a file, or a subdirectory, it's a share. That the Explorer manages to show it as a tree is another question. You wouldn't be able to enumerate the contents of `\Desktop\COMPUTER\Control Panel\Administrative Tools` either.

Comment: OK, so how do I list the shares on any host?

Comment: Worked! 
Thank you enlightened one :)

Comment: @Pascal: You should post that as an answer. :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091126/enumerating-network-shares-with-c