# Why .Net cannot list Network Shares?

Tags: .net, network-programming

I've found multiple answers to this particular need (like [Enumerating Network Shares with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091126/enumerating-network-shares-with-c-sharp)), but I keep wondering why this feature is not included into .Net Framework (WMI or PInvoke excluded) since I can see these into my Windows Explorer ?

Comment: _"since I can see these into my Windows Explorer"_ - I don't follow. Exporer isn't a .NET executable.

Comment: Oh, right... I just assumed I could have access to all Windows had by default using .Net like Windows Media Player from MediaElement, CMD from Process, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The network shares enumeration is a platform specific task, instead the .NET framework aims to be a cross platform fw!

Comment: How should it aim to be a cross plateform framework when it runs only on Windows (Mono and relatives excepted) ? (real question, I should have missed something then) [ EDIT : Sorry, I did miss that : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391(v=vs.110).aspx ]

Comment: I wrote "it aims to be" and not "it is"! :)

Comment: The argument keep his value to me in both ways =)