# Parallels Virtual machine causes unusable UNC paths in c#

Tags: c#, parallels

I am running my C# dev environment in a Win10 VM running under Parallels on OSX. It works well. However...

I have a form, and the form has a webBrowser control. And the webBrowser control wants to load an HTML page which is a local file, stored relative to the executable. But:

- if I set the `Url` property of the browser control to `file:///./web/mapping.html` then I get a "cannot find file" error. And yes, I've checked that the file is in the project `bin\Debug\web` folder.
- If I try doing it in code and using the `Application.Startup` parameter instead, so:

  ```
  this.mapWindow.Navigate(new Uri(Application.StartupPath + "\\web\\mapping.html"));
  ```

  (where `mapWindow` is the name of my browser control) then I get a UNC returned such as

  ```
  file://mac/home/Documents/Visual Studio 2015/Projects/WindowsFormsApplication1/WindowsFormsApplication1/bin/Debug/web/mapping.html
  ```

  and the browser is blank.

Parallels gives me a handy shortcut to `//mac/home` mapped onto the Z:\ drive, and if I use that (as an explicit path) then it works correctly. So my problem is getting the UNC as a local path. I've tried

[Convert UNC path to local path in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22953517/convert-unc-path-to-local-path-in-c-sharp)

but that seems to want a remote server ("mac" in this case) which it can't find, so I can't make that work either.

So should I give up, force it to be a direct path and only worry about it when I come to the final build, because it will be installed on a Windows box, or is there something that I can do?

I'm loathe to waste too much time solving something which might only affect my dev environment, but it does mean that I am building and testing something that I have to change, and hope it works, before the final build.

Answer (score 0):

Hah! Almost as soon as I had finished writing I stumbled across the answer by mistake.

If you set `Url` to something at design time - something that you know will be there all the time like www.google.com, then the `Navigate()` function works perfectly across the VM with the UNC.

Bizarre! But solved :)