# Read file on a remote server

Tags: c#, file, remote-access

I have a file on a remote server and I want to read this file.
lets say the files location is:

```
string filePath = @"\\192.168.101.15\c$\program files\xxx\test.xml";
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(filePath);
```

This code is for sure throwing an error:
Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.

How can I pass my credentials??

if I go start/run and put this path, I need to provide credentials lets say Admin and password 123.

Im using Asp.net, c# 3.5

Any Ideas

Comment: Look at 'Looking for best practice for doing a “Net Use” in C#' - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8919/looking-for-best-practice-for-doing-a-net-use-in-c

Answer (score 2):

You have to use impersonation, ie execute your code with a user who has acces to the shared folder instead of asp.net user :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa292118%28VS.71%29.aspx

You have two way :
-with code
-with configuration

Comment: I added to my web.config
    <identity impersonate="true"
          userName="domain\Admin"
          password="123" />

Im having the following error
 Configuration Error
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Could not create Windows user token from the credentials specified in the config file. Error from the operating system 'Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.

Answer (score 0):

Your application will need to run as a user that has access to the UNC path, or else impersonate a user with such permissions, for the file load operation.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to be pre-authenticated on the share before you can access the files. It isn't something you can do just by passing a UNC path.

You might consider executing a `net use` command via the shell programatically. That's the only way I can find to do this.

Comment: can u give me a link or an example how to do that
Thanks in advanced