# How to get file details using C# on a remote machine with username and password

Tags: c#

Tried to search for something similar but could not find.

I have file on a remote machine which I want to query for it`s details like version, date, etc.
How do I do that when I need to enter credentials for that machine?
FileVersionInfo does not give option to do so.

Thanks

Update:

As I said above I checked what FIleVersionInfo gives me (and also tried it) and that will not work for me.
I also tried using WMI and failed with (although it looked like the direction I need)
Here is the WMI code I tried - haven`t got much far:

```
var computerName = "IP_ADDRESS";
            ConnectionOptions conn = new ConnectionOptions();
            conn.Username = "username";
            conn.Password = "password";
            conn.Authority = "ntlmdomain:DOMAIN";
            conn.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
            conn.EnablePriviledges = true;
            var scope = new ManagementScope(String.Format("\\\\{0}\\root\\CIMV2", computerName), conn);


            scope.Connect();
            string Drive = "c:";
            string Path = "\\\\inetpub\\\\wwwroot\\\\FOLDER\\\BIN\\\File.dll";

            ObjectQuery Query = new ObjectQuery(string.Format("SELECT * FROM CIM_DataFile Where Drive='{0}' AND Path='{1}' ", Drive, Path));

            ManagementObjectSearcher Searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, Query);

            foreach (ManagementObject WmiObject in Searcher.Get())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", (string)WmiObject["Name"]);// String
            }
```

I mainly need the file properties version and date.

Thanks

Comment: Please show us your research.  Provide links and explain *explicitly* why they didn't answer your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417878/read-file-on-a-remote-server

Comment: What does your WMI code fail on? I've played around with it before and know it can be done. Have you tried setting the following flags in your WMI code?
[Impersonation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.connectionoptions.impersonation.aspx)
and [EnablePrivileges](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.connectionoptions.enableprivileges.aspx)

Comment: I have added the Impersonation as Impersonate and EnablePriviledges as true. I fail when I get to the Connect method.

Comment: @Draken Thanks. It was a mixture of your suggestions and mistaking in the domain name. Now I can carry on to get the details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Draken comment above I`ve added missing properties on the ConnectionOptions and also fixed my mistake on the domain name.

Here is the code I use to get to the file in the network PC

```
var computerName = "IP_ADDRESS";
        ConnectionOptions conn = new ConnectionOptions();
        conn.Username = "username";
        conn.Password = "password";
        conn.Authority = "ntlmdomain:DOMAIN";
        conn.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
        conn.EnablePriviledges = true;
        var scope = new ManagementScope(String.Format("\\\\{0}\\root\\CIMV2", computerName), conn);


        scope.Connect();
        string Drive = "c:";
        string Path = "\\\\inetpub\\\\wwwroot\\\\FOLDER\\\BIN\\\File.dll";

        ObjectQuery Query = new ObjectQuery(string.Format("SELECT * FROM CIM_DataFile Where Drive='{0}' AND Path='{1}' ", Drive, Path));

        ManagementObjectSearcher Searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, Query);

        foreach (ManagementObject WmiObject in Searcher.Get())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", (string)WmiObject["Name"]);// String
        }
```