# Map network drive: "net.exe USE" vs WshNetwork.MapNetworkDrive?

Tags: c#, windows, networking

I'm looking to map a drive in my program. My users can be using every version of Windows from XP on up. So I need the most versatile method. I have used the first method before and generally it's worked well for me. But there really isn't way to catch errors with it (that I know of anyway). The second will easily let me wrap a try/catch block around it, but for all the searching I've done for an alternatives to method 1, I've only run across method 2 once. So that leaves me to wonder if its reliable enough for such a varied environment. Can anyone tell me if method 2 is safe for most circumstances?

Method 1

```
Process.Start("net.exe", @"USE Z: \\server\share /user:domain\username password").WaitForExit();
```

Method 2 referencing the Windows Script Host Object Model

```
IWshNetwork_Class network = new IWshNetwork_Class(); 
network.MapNetworkDrive("k:", @"\\server\share");
```

Comment: I like #2. It looks cleaner, and was provided as part of an API. However, what about being able to specify credentials, etc?

Comment: Yes you can use credentials. I just left that out for clarity.

Comment: http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/mpr/WNetAddConnection2.html

Comment: Better practices for net use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8919/looking-for-best-practice-for-doing-a-net-use-in-c-sharp

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample working about it ?

Comment: I was approved to use the class mentioned in the accepted answer below. It works great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The other approach would be to pinvoke the actual Win32 apis (WNetAddConnection2A, WNetCancelConnection2A, etc).
Check out http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_network/windowsservices/article.php/c12357/

Comment: That would be perfect if it didn't use a 3rd party created class. I'm prevented from using them.

Comment: You don't need to use his class. You can create your own based on his work.