# How to use net user with c#

Tags: c#, .net, shell, command

I am trying to use net user with c#

```
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo proccessStartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("net user " + id + " /domain");

proccessStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process {StartInfo = proccessStartInfo};
proc.Start();

string result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
textBoxOp.Text = result;
```

When the I execute the code Win32 exception occurs with message **The system cannot find the file specified**

Details of exceptions are as follows

> at
>   System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo
>   startInfo)    at GetUserFromAD.Form1.GetInformation(String id) in
>   D:\GetUserFromAD\GetUserFromAD\Form1.cs:line 25    at
>   GetUserFromAD.Form1.button_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
>   D:\Ram\MyC#\GetUserFromAD\GetUserFromAD\Form1.cs:line 35    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons
>   button, Int32 clicks)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd,
>   Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
>   at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(Int32
>   dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)    at GetUserFromAD.Program.Main()
>   in D:\Ram\MyC#\GetUserFromAD\GetUserFromAD\Program.cs:line 18    at
>   System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
>   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    at
>   System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

Comment: I do not know the exact cause, work around i can say is put that statement in a batch script and pass that batch sript as argument to ProcessStartInfo API.

Comment: Better practices for net use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8919/looking-for-best-practice-for-doing-a-net-use-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`net` is the command. Everything from `user` onwards are command arguments. As such, you'll need to use the following constructor:

```
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo proccessStartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("net", "user " + id + " /domain");
```

**In addition**, in order to capture the standard output you'll need to set the following  properties before you call `proc.Start()`

```
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
```

Comment: Maybe Better practices for net use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8919/looking-for-best-practice-for-doing-a-net-use-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 2):

You need specify the path to net.exe which is located in a system directory (i.e. windows\system32). For example,

```
var proccessStartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(
    Path.Combine(Environment.SystemDirectory, "net.exe"), "user " + id + " /domain");
```

Also note that command line arguments are passed as a second parameter.

Comment: While it is better to specify the path to the command you want use, it is not strictly necessary as long as the command is on the user's path.

Answer (score 1):

```
 System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo proccessStartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "net user " + id + "/domain");
```