# How to set volume label?

Tags: c#

```
public void SetVolumeLabel(string newLabel)
{
    DriveInfo[] allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
    foreach (DriveInfo d in allDrives)
    {
        if (d.IsReady && d.DriveType == DriveType.Removable)
        {
            d.VolumeLabel = newLabel;
        }
    }
}

public string VolumeLabel { get; set; }

// Setting the drive name
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetVolumeLabel("FlashDrive");
}
```

But, It's not working with virtual drive. how to change volume label of virtual drive created by SUBST command?

Comment: What is *not working*?

Comment: What is the type of exception that is thrown ?

Comment: See [Rename a Subst/Virtual Drive In Windows](http://techie-buzz.com/how-to/rename-virtual-subst-drives-windows.html).

Comment: Error Message "Directory Is Not a Subdirectory of the Root Directory"

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this.

From [the Microsoft documentation for SUBST](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/subst.mspx?mfr=true):

```
The following commands do not work, or should not be used,
on drives used in the subst command:

chkdsk 
diskcomp 
diskcopy 
format 
label <------- NOTE
recover
```

Comment: is that any way to change volume label of virtual drive ? OR how to create virtual drive in c# without using SUBST command ?

Comment: @PavanModi You can also use something like `net use G: \\localhost\c$\Somefolder /persistent:yes`, but that doesn't allow setting the volume label either.

Comment: do you know how to create virtual drive in my computer using c# ?

Comment: @PavanModi The only way I know is to use the shell via class Process to run the Label or Net commands.

Comment: can i have a example of how to use 'shell via class Process to run the Label or Net commands'?

Comment: @PavanModi Examples here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9905719/how-to-use-net-user-with-c-sharp

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33970/discussion-between-pavan-modi-and-matthew-watson)

Comment: 'shell via class Process to run the Label' : These steps only work for physical drives. How to perform rename If the drive has been created with the subst command or another software utility?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know of any way to do that.

Comment: Is it possible to change volume name of Virtual Drive without Admin right ?

Answer (score 1):

Try following code

```
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool SetVolumeLabel(string lpRootPathName, string lpVolumeName);
    public static void Main()
    {
        string name = "E:\\";
        var status = SetVolumeLabel(name, "Test");
        var error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
        Console.WriteLine(status + " " + error);
    }
```

refer http://www.pinvoke.net/ for more help.
refer this link if status is false, to understand [error](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

On my system I am unable to change the volume label of a virtual drive even though the drive it is created from has no drive label, but there is a "for display only" workaround that works on my Windows 7 machine: Open My Computer, click on the virtual drive to highlight it, then wait a second, then click once on the drive letter. This will give you the option to rename the drive by typing something in and hitting enter. This normally will change the drive label, but because you aren't able to change the drive label of a virtual drive Windows instead creates this registry key: `HKEY_USERS\{your SID}\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\DriveIcons\{drive letter}\DefaultLabel` to display the label to you. This DOES NOT change the drive label, it only allows you to give a sort of display name to the virtual drive in explorer. But for some people this may be all they need.

Comment: I think he asked for a c# solution that works, but I like your answer.