# C# explorer network share by username and password which is not a domain user and just as same workgroup

Tags: c#

I have a windows app where the user presses a button and it opens explorer.exe to a specific network share such as "\192.168.0.100\share".  I would like it to log the user into the share automatically. The user using the app is a common user, not a domain user, such as username:"user1" and password:"pass1". that server is same workgroup with local computer, such as workgroup:"WORKGROUP". that server's name is such as "FileServer" and ip address is such as "192.168.1.100". and the credentials needed for the share are local users on that server, therefore they are prompted for authentication. Is there a way to automate this so they dont have to manually login? I programming by C#. Please!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to save the credentials before you launch the explorer window.

```
net use \\192.168.1.100 YourUsersPassword /USER:FileServer\YourUser
```

Once this is saved, you can launch as many explorer windows on the share.

However, `net.exe`  is a windows command, how you want to execute it in your C# app is up to you:

http://channel9.msdn.com/Forums/TechOff/242590-The-best-way-to-effect-quotnet-usequot-from-C

[Looking for best practice for doing a "Net Use" in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8919/looking-for-best-practice-for-doing-a-net-use-in-c-sharp)